# Alternative to calling same function twice on a select query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a select query for a view which is like

```
SELECT
    c.id,
    c.name,
    p.name   AS person_name,
    fetch_selected_student_of_class(c.id) as student,
    fetch_selected_section(fetch_selected_student_of_class(c.id), c.id) as section
    FROM
    class   c
    left JOIN persons                  p ON c.room_id = p.id
```

Here the function `fetch_selected_student_of_class` is repeated twice. So the function would be executed twice. Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a subquery:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, p.name   AS person_name, c.student,
       fetch_selected_section(c.student, c.id) as section
FROM (SELECT c.*, fetch_selected_student_of_class(c.id) as student
      FROM class c
     ) c LEFT JOIN
     persons p
     ON c.room_id = p.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You ca do something like this.

```
select *,fetch_selected_section(d.student, c.id) as section from 
(
SELECT
c.id,
c.name,
p.name   AS person_name,
fetch_selected_student_of_class(c.id) as student,

FROM
class   c
left JOIN persons                  p ON c.room_id = p.id
) d
```